# How combine multiple WHEN in Pyspark

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I have a pyspark dataframe that contain 4 columns.

```
id  |  name  | age |  job
----------------------------
```

I want to use 3 columns `(array<string> type)` in when clause, and to keep only the values of one column.
So, I did it using when but I got an error:

```
new_df = my_df.select("id","name","age","job").withColumn("coordinate", F.when(F.size(F.col("id")) > 0, my_df["id"]).when(F.size(F.col("name")) > 0, my_df["name"]).when(F.size(F.col("age")) > 0, my_df["age"]).otherwise("null"))
```

A small resume of the error:

```
AnalysisException: u"cannot resolve 'CASE WHEN (size(`id`) > 0) THEN `id` WHEN (size()...... name` WHEN (size() ..... age WHEN (size) ....
    ELSE 'null' END' due to data type mismatch: THEN and ELSE expressions should all be same type or coercible to a common type;;
```

How can I resolve it ? Thank you

Comment: Please give a reproducible data sample. If your `coordinate` is gonna contain `array<string>` then  `.otherwise("null")` should have an array like `.otherwise(F.array(None))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to populate in *coordinate* column in case of empty input arrays, *null* or *empty array*

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(['1','2'], ['a', 'b'], ['30', '40'], 'it'),([], [], [], 'it')], ['id', 'name', 'age', 'job'])

df.withColumn("coordinate", F.when(F.size("id") > 0, df["id"]).when(F.size("name") > 0, df["name"]).when(F.size("age") > 0, df["age"]).otherwise(None)).show()
+------+------+--------+---+----------+
|    id|  name|     age|job|coordinate|
+------+------+--------+---+----------+
|[1, 2]|[a, b]|[30, 40]| it|    [1, 2]|
|    []|    []|      []| it|      null|
+------+------+--------+---+----------+

df.withColumn("coordinate", F.when(F.size("id") > 0, df["id"]).when(F.size("name") > 0, df["name"]).when(F.size("age") > 0, df["age"]).otherwise(F.array(F.lit(None)))).show()
+------+------+--------+---+----------+
|    id|  name|     age|job|coordinate|
+------+------+--------+---+----------+
|[1, 2]|[a, b]|[30, 40]| it|    [1, 2]|
|    []|    []|      []| it|        []|
+------+------+--------+---+----------+
```